# How to get this to run in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am being tasked with getting this line of code that another team made to run in PowerShell and to loop through a text document full of IDs. The IDs will replace the previous ID with each pass of the loop but the base of the code needs to run and I haven't seen code like this before so I am not exactly sure how to get it to run.

```
ren y:\$one y:\$one.old && add-adgroupmember -identity sms.personalfoldersuuh -members $one & remove-adgroupmember -identity "myFolder folders clinic" -members $one & robocopy y:\$one.old z:\$one /MIR /copyall /R:0 /XD ~snapshot /MT:128
```

I was thinking just create the loop which I know how to do with no issues and put this in there but that doesn't work. I am trying to dissect this code and it looks like the & are just piping. I guess my question is will someone help me go through this code and make sense of it? I know ren is rename, which if I could just keep it as ren and have it run great because it works and I get the other parts that are powershell. But I don't know how to make it all work within the loop.

Comment: Open a cmd.exe window and type >Help CMD which will explain everything.

Comment: add-adgroupmember is a powershell cmdlet so presumably works already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to break this down for you. Also, I think there is an error in the formatting. Each `&` should be `&&` perhaps?

#### ren y:\$one y:\$one.old

This renames an existing folder (or file) to have the `.old` extension, so it moves out, so to say.

#### add-adgroupmember -identity sms.personalfoldersuuh -members $one

This is is adding the the member (or value) in `$one` to the `sms.personalfoldersuuh` group in Active Directory.

#### remove-adgroupmember -identity "myFolder folders clinic" -members $one

Removing the member (or value) in `$one` from the `myFolders folders clinic` group in Active Directory.

#### robocopy y:$one.old z:$one /MIR /copyall /R:0 /XD ~snapshot /MT:128

Robocopy command. Here is the breakdown:

- `y:\$one.old`: Specifies the source directory to copy from. This is the directory that was renamed earlier in the script.
- `z:\$one`: Specifies the destination directory to copy to. This is where the renamed directory will be copied to.
- `/MIR`: Mirrors the source directory and destination directory. This means that any files or folders in the destination directory that don't exist in the source directory will be deleted.
- `/COPYALL`: Copies all file information, including permissions, attributes, timestamps, and ownership information.
- `/R:0`: Specifies the number of times to retry if a file copy fails. In this case, it will not retry if a file copy fails.
- `/XD ~snapshot`: Excludes the "~snapshot" directory from being copied. This is a system directory created by some backup software.
- `/MT:128`: Specifies the number of threads to use when copying files. In this case, it will use up to 128 threads to copy files. 128 is fast. :-)